# Why am i getting this error in the angular.min.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey after installing angular i made a simple routing script and for some reason the console is saying there is an error in the angular.min.js and i do not know why becuse i got it directly from the anularjs.org website. The console is showing this error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=englishHosts&p1=Err…
localhost%2Fvendor%2Fbuild%2FAngularJavascript%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4683
    at q (angular.js:325)
    at g (angular.js:4644)
    at eb (angular.js:4566)
    at c (angular.js:1803)
    at Ic (angular.js:1824)
    at ue (angular.js:1709)
    at angular.js:32379
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3251)
```

My index.html has

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="englishHosts">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../vendor/libs/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../vendor/libs/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../vendor/build/AngularJavascript/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/build/AngularJavascript/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module("englishHosts", ["ngRoute"]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This error still occurs without the app.js. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Try removing `..` from the `src` attribute

Comment: Tried it still shows error

Comment: if you actually used `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`, the error would be clear.  If I had to make a ***guess***, it would be that `ngRoute` isn't loading right, since that is literally the only thing here that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'modulerr' error because you don't define the module englishHosts.

Your app.js must contains something like this:

```
angular.module('englishHosts',[]);
```

And don't forget:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

This appears in the http link : http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=englishHosts...

(look at the p0 parameter in the url)

If you follow this 'error link', you will have some details.

Comment: It shows solutions but i have tried those i am using 1.5.9 version witch is above 1.3.0 and it shows `angular.module('ng').filter('tel', function (){});` is a bad practice but i declared it like `var app = angular.module("englishHosts", ["ngRoute"]);` so i really do not know why it is not working

Comment: `var app = angular.module("englishHosts", ["ngRoute"]);` is the only thing in app.js right now untill i figure out the error

Comment: The html you post don't have a link to your js file(s), is it normal?

Comment: It is linked and i am setting the angular.module correctly and i am still getting an error i will put a demo up so yall can see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are seeing is because you are defining in the html

`<html lang="en" ng-app="englishHosts">`

and it cannot find the module called `englishHosts`

```js
//  When this is commented out it will throw an error because it cannot find the module declared in the html !
// var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" >
  
</div>
```

Comment: I defined it in the body and still getting error, no matter where i define it i still get the error

Comment: where is the js that defines the module ?

Comment: Srry i have not responded i was at work ill update my question

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.